# How to speed up the movement of the object?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skaction

In the scene of a finger you can move the object. But if you just speed up the movement of the finger on the screen - the object remains in place. Is it possible to accelerate the speed of its movement? Duration is already set to 0

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch = touches.first
    let touchLocation = touch!.locationInNode(self)
    let node = self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)

    if (node.name == "circle") {

        let moveAction = SKAction.moveTo(touchLocation, duration: 0)

        figureUser.runAction(moveAction)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not the speed,  your problem is you are moving so fast on the screen, that your touch is not recognizing a node underneath it anymore because the node is physically not underneath it.  How you handle this problem is on the touch begin event,  you check for a node,  and assign this node to a variable.  Then on the touch move event,  update the new variable.  Finally on touch end,  clear the variable.  Note, you would need to handle this code for things like multi touch

```
var movingNode : SKNode?
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)     {

    let touch = touches.first
    let touchLocation = touch!.locationInNode(self)
    let node = self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)

    if (node.name == "circle") {
        movingNode = node
        let moveAction = SKAction.moveTo(touchLocation, duration: 0)

        figureUser.runAction(moveAction)
    }
}
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)     {

    let touch = touches.first
    let touchLocation = touch!.locationInNode(self)

        let moveAction = SKAction.moveTo(touchLocation, duration: 0)
     //at this point I am lost,  how does node even relate here,  
     //is figureUser suppose to be node?
        figureUser.runAction(moveAction)

}
```